# Encoded HTML string incorrectly decoded in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I post data containing an html string as well as some other data from JavaScript to the PHP (Codeigniter) server w/ AJAX & JSON.

The HTML string contains an image tag w/ some style data. On the server, the style info is gone! The rest of the data I post is just fine.

What should I do to the HTML string to prevent this?

JavaScript side:

```
my_html='<p><img alt="" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/ferns.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 133px;" /></p>';
my_count=1;
```

This is the data that gets posted in the AJAX call:

```
form_data='my_html='+encodeURIComponent(my_html)+'&my_count='+my_count;
```

On the server:

```
$html_str=$this->input->post('my_html');
$this->chromephp->log($html_str);
```

And this is what it prints:

```
<p><img alt="" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/ferns.jpg"  /></p>
```

**EDIT - 1/24/18**
After more investigation, it seems to be a decoding issue or the way I'm reading the value in Codeigniter (v 2). Nothing to do with the fact it's an image tag.

Here's what I've figured out -

Javascript:

```
var hstr ='<p style="color:red;">Hello</p>';
```

After encodeURIComponent(), encoded string submitted as form data:

```
%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3Ared%3B%22%3EHello%3C%2Fp%3E
```

But, in the server:

The (URIencoded string being submitted as form data over AJAX:
     $html_str=$this->input->post('hstr');
     $this->chromephp->log($html_str);

yields:

```
<p >Hello</p>
```

On the server if I urldecode() the encoded string directly,

```
$xx=urldecode('%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3Ared%3B%22%3EHello%3C%2Fp%3E');
$this->chromephp->log($xx);
```

yields:

```
<p style="color:red;">Hello</p>
```

So is it that Codeigniter (v2) decodes it when I use input->post()? Is there a way to get the raw undecoded string?

Any suggestions?

Help! Please!

Mmiz

Comment: `urlencode()` it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FencodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
form_data='my_html='+encodeURI(my_html)+'&my_count='+my_count;
```

Comment: @ChristianPastorCruz - I was actually encoding it in my code - I failed to include that in my code snippet in the question. Will edit my question to fix this. Still seems to strip out style in the html string.